# What is the best data structure in Perl to store tabular data?

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I have a table with the following data

```
1.1.1.1   routerA  texas
2.2.2.2   routerB  texas
3.3.3.3   routerC  california
```

What is the best data structure in Perl to store this data? I am thinking of storing in a hash of hash with the IP address as the key

```
1.1.1.1 
 routerA => texas,
2.2.2.2
 routerB => texas,
3.3.3.3
 routerC => california
```

But if I want to get all the IP addresses in texas, my data structure may not be flexible enough. Is there a better way to store this if I care about all IP addresses in Texas?

Comment: If you really want this kind of flexibility, maybe you want a relational database?

Comment: Seems like something you could be representing effectively with SQLite.

Comment: I agree with @DavidO, this seems like a job for a database.

Comment: I happen to disagree with the above comments.  Perl handles the OP's application rather nicely, provided only that one is handy with Perl's hashes and its `map` statement.  Perl takes a little more work to represent the data, but then is more programmably flexible as to what one does with the data.

Comment: @thb I'd love to see how you would handle the OP's application with hashes and `map`. Wouldn't you want to post an answer demonstrating it (since I couldn't think of a nice all perl solution right away)?

Comment: Is this the only operation you require? I mean you just want to query for all IP addresses at a location? What other kind of queries your are looking out for?

Comment: @kratenko:  Thanks.  I have done as you say.  Does the answer suit?

Comment: @thb already commented and upvoted...

Comment: What sorts of questions about the data do you expect to ask? How much volume should you plan to handle?

Comment: The best data structure depends on what you want to do with the data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pure Perl is definitely up to this task.

Think of a table as an array of records. In Perl speak, that is an array of hash references. (An AoA may be applicable at times, remember TIMTOWTDI)

The keys of each hash reference correspond to the column/field name and the values will be, well, the values for that particular record.

Converting the OP's example to a data structure:

```
my @data = (
             {
                ip     => '1.1.1.1',
                router => 'routerA',
                state  => 'texas',
             },
             {
                ip     => '2.2.2.2',
                router => 'routerB',
                state  => 'texas',
             },
             {
                ip     => '3.3.3.3',
                router => 'routerA',
                state  => 'california',
             }
           );
```

Now for the fun part:

```
# Give me all IPs in Texas

my @ips_in_texas = map $_->{ip},
                    grep { $_->{state} =~ /texas/i }
                     @data;

# How many states does the data cover?

use List::MoreUtils 'uniq';

my $states_covered = uniq( map $_->{state}, @data );

# How many unique IPs in each state?

my %ips_by_state;
$ips_by_state{ $_->{state} }{ $_->{ip} }++ for @data;
print "'$_': ", scalar keys %{ $ips_by_state{$_} }, "\n" for keys %ips_by_state;
```

---

The knee-jerk reaction I often get when I suggest this data structure centers around its hunger for memory. Frankly speaking, it won't be an issue unless you're dealing with millions of records. And if that is the case, a DBMS is the pencil-sharpening solution you seek, not Perl.

Comment: I am familiar with the knee-jerk reaction.  You are right.  The principal, practical advantage of SQL in cases like this is that one needn't be a programmer to use it.  If you are a programmer, then you'll often find the Perl more flexible.  You are correct about the memory, though, on both points.

Answer (score 4):

I know, it's not perl... but how about a [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) table in memory? Fast, flexibel, portable and even persistable. You could do a lot more complicated things there, then look for all IPs in Texas...

Answer (score 4):

Your suggestion to use a hash of hashes with the IP address as the key is exactly how I would do this.  However, you will also have to build a separate, secondary, cross-reference hash, in which the states (like Texas) are the keys and the IP addresses are the data.  In the secondary hash, each state is a key, and the corresponding value is itself a hash.  In the inner hashes, the keys are IPs and the values are dummy values, conventionally the value 1.

In your example, here is the secondary, cross-reference hash:

```
california
 { 3.3.3.3 => 1 },
texas
 { 1.1.1.1 => 1, 2.2.2.2 => 1 }
```

You can write a short subroutine/function/block that builds the secondary hash from the primary.  It's a little harder if the data set is large *and* often updated, but the idea is the same.

You will find it easier to write the code that does the above if you first grasp Perl's almost-too-cute but nonetheless rather handy *autovivification* feature:  see the manpages *perlreftut* and *perlref.*